# 2D Screen Coordinates to 2D World Coordinates in LWJGL

Tags: 2d, lwjgl, mouse, lwjgl3

I'm making a 2d top down game with lwjgl and am having trouble converting my 2d screen coordinates to 2d world coordinates.

Here's what I have so far

```
 private Vector2f toWorldCoords(Vector4f eyeCoords) {
    Matrix4f invertedView = Matrix4f.invert(MathUtil.createViewMatrix(camera), null);
    Vector4f rayWorld = Matrix4f.transform(invertedView, eyeCoords, null);
    Vector2f mouseRay = new Vector2f(rayWorld.x, rayWorld.y);
    mouseRay.normalise();
    return mouseRay;
}

public Vector2f screenToWorld(Vector2f mouseCoords) {
    Vector2f normalizedCoords = CursorHandler.getNormalisedDeviceCoordinates();
    Vector4f clipCoords = new Vector4f(normalizedCoords.x, normalizedCoords.y, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    Vector2f worldRay = toWorldCoords(clipCoords);

    return worldRay;
}
```

I understand it's been asked before, and I've tried following some 3d tutorials that deal with the same topic, but so far I haven't been able to use the code successfully.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple really.
Your camera must be an orthographic projection so the formula for screen to camera is:

```
Vector2f cameraPosition = new Vector2f(screenPosition.x - Camera.getWidth() / 2, screenPosition.y - Camera.getHeight() / 2);
```

Then to world coordinates:

```
Vector2f worldPosition = cameraPosition.add(Camera.getPosition());
```

Keep in mind that you'll probably need to invert the camera's position.

```
Vector2f invertedCameraPosition = camera.getPosition().mul(-1, new Vector2f());
```